# LAMP Server crashing but memory and processor use are low

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, apache, performance

I'm having some bad times with my application running on a LAMP server.
I'll explain the scenario and below I'll tell my configuration and some AB results.

I'm running an application developed with Laravel 4.2. 
It's a quizz game and at a certain time we have a group quizz with 4 users per group.
When they reach this stage, there is a lot of ajax requests (to check the correct time, as JS timers are imprecise I request to the database each 3 seconds and save the current time in the database), each 2 seconds I check for answers in a chat room for each group (everything is stored in a MySQL database)

My server is handling up nicely until 200, 300 users simultaneously but when it reaches 400, 500 users the server start to be very slow until everything turns into a nightmare and nobody can play anymore.

The ajax requests are simple php files with an select and insert queries without nestled loops, joins and other stuff that can slow down the app.

Here is some information: 
Server config: 
-SSD VPS on RAMNode. 
-8GB RAM
- 40GB SSD
- 4 vCores

Services info: 
Ubuntu server 14.4
Apache 2.4.7
PHP 5.5.9
MySQL 5.5.47
Laravel 4.2

I don't have any other services running on this server.
Memory usage on peak (600 users at the same time playing the group game): 1.5GB
Processor usage: 22%.

AB Results:

```
root@server01:~# ab -r -n 27000 -c 900 -k -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip,             deflate"  http://repensegame.com.br/shout_benchmark.php
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1528965 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking repensegame.com.br (be patient)
Completed 2700 requests
Completed 5400 requests
Completed 8100 requests
Completed 10800 requests
Completed 13500 requests
Completed 16200 requests
Completed 18900 requests
Completed 21600 requests
Completed 24300 requests
Completed 27000 requests
Finished 27000 requests


Server Software:        Apache/2.4.7
Server Hostname:        repensegame.com.br
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /shout_benchmark.php
Document Length:        687 bytes

Concurrency Level:      900
Time taken for tests:   157.934 seconds
Complete requests:      27000
Failed requests:        10265
(Connect: 0, Receive: 296, Length: 9673, Exceptions: 296)
Keep-Alive requests:    0
Total transferred:      24637886 bytes
HTML transferred:       18335742 bytes
Requests per second:    170.96 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       5264.454 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       5.849 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          152.35 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0  113 942.5      0   15004
Processing:    63 2302 11425.2    581  121540
Waiting:        0 1300 6014.9    579  102647
Total:         91 2415 11791.8    583  122541

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    583
  66%    600
  75%    611
  80%    621
  90%    684
  95%   1554
  98%  60434
  99%  64164
 100%  122541 (longest request)
root@server01:~# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          8192       1518       6673         72          0       1318
-/+ buffers/cache:        200       7991
Swap:          256          0        256
root@server01:~#
```

httpd.conf:

```
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers 10
    MinSpareServers 8
    MaxSpareServers 128
    MaxClients 2048
    ServerLimit  8000
</IfModule>

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-    Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""     combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

ExtendedStatus On
```

Vhost conf.:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public
    ServerName repensegame.com.br
    <Directory /var/www/html/public>
            allow from all
            Options None
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Location /server-status>
        SetHandler server-status
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from localhost
    </Location>
    ServerAlias *.repensegame.com.br
</VirtualHost>
```

I didn't detected any slow query.

That's it.
Sorry for the wall text.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: your hitting the home page with ab will not lead to any usefull result. It's the actuall pages that your users access that you need to visit. Anyway 500 concurrent users is quite a lot you know. This might possibly be the maximum number of users your hardware can handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MaxClients` = 2048 is deadly.  I tend to recommend 20.  You noted that 300 might be ok.  But that was just for the benchmark?  Not real life?

It is especially bad if `max_connections` is less that that.

At some point (which varies with the application), it is better to queue the request *instead of* getting the request started, only to have it contend for resources, thereby delaying response time *without* improving throughput.

What was `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Max_used_connections';`?  What is `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  (Sounds like it is lower than it should be.)